# Can't get a link render properly on email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to construct a string that will be passed to UserMailer as the body of the email.

Here is the code:

```
html_text = ""
topic_object.title = "Example title"
topic_object.body = "Example body"
html_text << 'Visit the page by <a href="http://localhost.com/topic_digests/#{topic_object.slug}>" clicking here</a>.<br>'
html_text << topic_object.title
html_text << topic_object.body
```

then I have this line for delivering the email

```
UserMailer.dynamic_actual_digest(current_user.email, html_text).deliver
```

My challenge is that I can't get the `clicking here` text hyperlinked properly with the url I need. It doesn't render it. I tried link_to, I tried double quotes and I tried `<%= topic_object.slug %>`.

I believe the trouble is that there is a need for both double and single quotes on the same line even if I use the `link_to` method or the `a` html tag.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct string using `%Q` [syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation):

```
html_text = ""
topic_object.title = "Example title"
topic_object.body = "Example body"
html_text << %Q|Visit the page by <a href="http://localhost.com/topic_digests/#{topic_object.slug}>" clicking here</a>.<br>|
html_text << topic_object.title
html_text << topic_object.body
UserMailer.dynamic_actual_digest(current_user.email, html_text).deliver
```

and try sending explicit html with `html_safe` directive inside your `user_mailer.rb`:

```
def dynamic_actual_digest(email, html_text)
  mail(to: email) do |format|
    format.html { render html: html_text.html_safe }
  end
end
```